# Build Qt 4.8.6 VS 2010 express. Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, qt4

I have VS 2012 x64 prof and VS 2010 express installed on my computer. I want to build Qt 4.8.6 with VS 2010 express. I downloaded zip from Qt site. Added "C:\Qt\qt-4.8.6\qmake" to my PATH, added environment variable

> QMAKESPEC == win32-msvc2010

Run in VS 2010 command prompt

> C:\Qt\qt-4.8.6\configure -release

and got error:

```
c:\qt\qt-4.8.6\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h(45) : fatal err
or C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
```

What could be a problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you ran the VS2010 command prompt? Can you try to "source" VCVARS32.BAT in that prompt or in a regular Windows prompt?

Comment: @lpapp Yes, this is vs 2010 command prompt.. I did "@echo %VSINSTALLDIR%
echo %FrameworkDir32%
echo %FrameworkVersion32%
echo %Framework35Version%
echo %WindowsSdkDir%" inside VCVARS32.BAT. Everything seems to be fine: 'Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\
v4.0.30319
v3.5
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\' Can it be because of express edition? I did not use it before, only VS 2012. May be I need to install smth?

Comment: Just in case: you are trying to build x86 on x86 and not mixing x86 with x86_64, right? Can you write a simple main.c like this: `#include <stddef.h> int main() { return 0; }` and run it through cl.exe? Does it build?

Comment: @lapp Yes, you are right, thanks! It does not compile, same error. But what am I mixing here? I installed VS 2010 on Win7, ran x86 compiler. Could you please explain what I need to change? Thank you!

Comment: No, sorry, that sounds miracle to me. You may need to ask the Oracle from Matrix (j/k). Have you tried running `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86` before `cl.exe main.c`?

Comment: @lapp Same error.. I will try to reinstall studio.

Answer (score -2):

1 reason for this may be that the version of QT is not corresponding to the version of Visual basic.
The Qt 5.3 for VS2013 package
Because their compiler are not compatible from version to another and even less with MinGW
You read right but their’s currently packages provided for the last 3 versions of Visual Studio plus MinGW.
You try installing the latest versions on both. I think that will help.

Comment: I have python project that uses PyQT4 package. PyQt5 and 4 are not compatible. That is why I need to install Qt4. I tried to biuld Qt 4.8.6 version with VS 2010 express. As I understood from site, Qt4 can  be built with VS 2010 and VS 2008

Comment: The OP seems to be using Qt 4.8.6, not sure where you got 5.3. from and VS2013 ...